# Bootstrap theme on my Telerik asp.net ajax controls

Tags: webforms, telerik, themes, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to use bootstrap on my Telerik asp.net ajax controls. 
I used the theme builder to generate a custom layout just the basic bootstrap layout no changes.

this is what I see in the inspection before the download:
[image]

Then I download it and get a zip file with a bunch of css files, no images or font files.

I follow the instructions I found [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/appearance-and-styling/modifying-existing-skins#creating-a-custom-skin-basic-steps)

- Copy one of our existing skins (CSS and images). For example the Vista skin.
- Modify the corresponding CSS classes definitions in the CSS file.
- Change the urls for the images referenced in the CSS file.(no image so I don't do this)
- Register your CSS file in the HEAD section of your page.
- Set Skin="" and EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" for RadGrid.

This is what I get:
[image]

When I inspect an element in the html on Teleriks web sit I see this but in a button icon.

```
.RadFileExplorer .RadToolBar .rtbImage {
font-family: "WebComponentsIcons"; <-- wtf!!? 
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1;
```

}

I don't have this "WebComponentsIcons" locally when I inspect. I'm missing something do I actually need a skin or something even with the themes.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't standard Bootstrap skin from Telerik an option or you need it to be custom?

Comment: Bingo!, you are correct just dusting off the webforms cobwebs. please put something in the answer section so I can give you some much deserved points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik has a standard built-in bootstrap skin for ASP. NET AJAX, please see [Telerik's Built-in Skins list](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/controlling-visual-appearance/how-skins-work) for more information!